# Problem in chrome, HTML Form in div over a div

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've got 3 div's on my page, one is the form which is last in the code and positioned ontop of the first 2 divs. In Google Chrome when I try click the form fields it wont let me unless I click the bottom bit of input boxes or the very top of radio buttons.

I've confirmed the problem is with having divs behind it by removing the other 2 divs, and it worked fine after.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Code:

```
<div id="info_top"></div>  
<div id="info_bottom"></div>  
<div id="tabs">  
    <ul>  
        <li><a href="ahah_1.html" title="tabcontent"><span>tab1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="ahah_2.html" title="tabcontent"><span>tab2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="ahah_3.html" title="tabcontent"><span>tab3</span></a></li>
    </ul>  
    <div id="tabcontent"> ... </div>  
</div>
```

`info_top`, `info_bottom` and `tabs` have their positions set as absolute with the `tabs` div sitting over the other 2. The form gets loaded into the `tabcontent` div.

Link: http://hintswen.com/tempstack/trunk/ use second link on that page to open it, the form is on the last tab (top row).

Comment: @Hintswen, thanks for the html, but if your problem is related to the css positioning, it might help if we could see the css, too. Or a link to a live example?

Comment: @Hintswen: thank you. That's...interesting, isn't it? The obvious solution is to simply move the two divs causing the problem, perhaps `display: none` if you don't need them visible anyway?

Comment: Just checked and it does the same thing in FireFox but works fine in IE8. The only thing I can think of is removing the divs that are underneath while the tabs are shown. I don't see why that wouldn't work, it's a workaround but i'd rather not do it like that. If worst comes to worst then that's my fallback.

Comment: Well I'll either need the tabs div or the other 2 divs visible at any time. I wanted to keep the other 2 divs there so I wouldn't have to mess with showing/hiding them when needed, I would just need to show/hide the tabs div.

Comment: Yeah; it's not ideal. I'm sorry to say that I don't even understand *why* the underlying content would affect the form. If you move the inputs/labels outside of the table, so it's just within a fieldset, does the same problem occur? I'm fascinated, now...

Comment: same problem if it's not in the table. Just added a new field above the username text, its not in the table.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'm not sure if this would work, but try setting a large value of '[z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp)' for the 'ul' tag</strike>

**Edit**: Set the value of z-index to -1 for both divs, it works (in firefox, at least)

Comment: with z-index set to -1 when the tabs div is hidden they wont show so i'm back to changing it every time i want to show/hide the tabs div.

Comment: I don't know ... couldn't figure it out .. I'll try some more :)

Comment: I can actually go with hiding it when the tabs are visible because the tabs are visible most of the time anyway. The only time the divs underneath are visible is when you switch pages. So the only place I need to put the code to hide them is the part that opens the tabs.

I'm just going to do that. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem

I have experienced similar div depths problems and resolved by this before

put this css on 'div' tags

```
div { zoom: 1 }
```